# Find the RED meat!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Find this special RED meat.

> Finger licking RED meat.. But flies won't dare to touch it.

Clue 1:

> It is damn hot & I'm not sure if I add tag [lateral-thinking].

Clue 2:

> It actually looks like spicy cooked red meat, but not real meat :(.

Final Clue:

> There is a JavaScript Framework with the same name!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

due to last clue my guess is

> Ember

Question clue (provided by Javy):

> When someone touches a piece of Ember they would immediately lick the finger.

clue 1

> its damn hot as its a small piece of burning or glowing coal or wood in a dying fire.

clue 2

> glowing coal looks like meat but if a fly touches it they will die

clue 3

> JavaScript framework Ember.js

Comment: Not Java , but Javascript and about Finger licking I thought of when someone touches a piece of Ember we immediately licks the finger. I'll accept this answer as this was posted first

Comment: I meant JavaScript  was typing fast to get the answer ready haha nice riddle good job

Comment: And I am now laughing at my "finger-licking" explanation ;)

Answer (score 13):

Finger licking RED meat.. But flies won't dare to touch it.

> It is tongue.

Or

> Maybe it is a red electric insect fly flapper.

Comment: good one, but not the answer. note the **wordplay** tag

Answer (score 5):

Fairly confident it is

> **Meteor**. (aka MeteorJS)

Because

> there is lots of emphasis on MEAT in the question, meat is a common play on words for jokes/puns based on the word meteor.

Clue 1:

> It is damn hot & I'm not sure if I add tag [lateral-thinking].
>  **A: From what i last read about them, meteors are pretty damn hot due to the friction of entering our atmosphere.**

Clue 2:

> It actually looks like spicy cooked red meat, but not real meat :(.
>  **A: never seen one in person, but perhaps a meteor does look like a peppered steak**

Final Clue:

> There is a JavaScript Framework with the same name!
>  **A: Meteor is a javascript framework**

Answer (score 3):

well last clue was the key,
it is

> ember

not sure though

> An ember is a glowing, hot coal. It is hot, so flies wont dare to touch it,
> it looks like spicy meat, but not actual meat,and i guess figure licking, referring to the Ember Restaurant?

Comment: Hello Smriti Welcome to Puzzling SE , Your answer is very close.

Comment: @smriti An edit must always be done such that you keep the original answer, and then mention it as an edit to add the new answer based on any new clues you got. Simply replacing is not recommended.

Comment: @CinCout well,this is my first answer, i will take the note

Comment: Good. Kindly revert your answer as per the suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

It is:

> Ember

The last clue was enough! Being a programmer helps ;)

Explanation:

> Ember is "a small piece of burning or glowing coal or wood in a dying fire". It looks like RED meat, and obviously the flies are not fools to dare touch it! As far as "finger licking" is concerned, since embers are part of pyre, the dead body's fingers it will lick!

Answer (score 1):

I guess it may be

> **deer** (looks like "dare")

Comment: Nop , and flies can touch a deer, added a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess

> A Happy Meal burger ? i've read somewhere Flies dont dare to touch a happy meal.